# Convert google analytics date to human readable value

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am getting Google Analytics data via API using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Everything fine except one thing, I can't convert day timestamp into readable value. The day timestamp looks like 20150724, `date('M j', $date);` always shows **Aug 22** even for different timestamps.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't tell PHP what the number is, it will assume it's a UNIX timestamp. 20150724 is 22nd August 1970...

So just tell it how it's formatted:

```
<?php
$google_date = '20150724';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $google_date);
echo $date->format('M j');
```

Answer (score 1):

date() expects the $date to be a timestamp which is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch. Try converting $date with strtotime.